# NameError: name 'obj' is not defined на 3D движке

Tags: python

Я пытался добавить не статичный спрайт в свой 3Д движок. Однако, после добавления у меня был ряд ошибок в программе, которые я пофиксил, однако осталась проблема.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\UN3D\main.py", line 27, in <module>
    drawing.world(walls + [obj.object_locate(player, walls) if obj else sprites.list_of_objects])
NameError: name 'obj' is not defined
```

Дело в том, что у меня в другом файле уже объявлен obj, но в main он не читается.

```
def world(self, world_objects):
        for obj in sorted(world_objects, key=lambda n: n[0], reverse=True):
            if obj[0]:
                _, object, object_pos = obj
                self.sc.blit(object, object_pos)
```

Я пробовал в файле main объявить obj, но позже он и не находил object_locate. Вторпой день ломаю голову, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А чем мы поможем? Вы в вызове метода `world` используете переменную `obj`. Но она нигде до этого не была определена. Определитесь, что это за объект и откуда он возникает.

Comment: Что вы проверяете тут `if obj`?

Comment: Прорисовка и позиция объекта.